# Does RxJs .first() operator (among others) complete the source observable?

Tags: rxjs

If I have the following code:

```
const subject = new BehaviorSubject<[]>([]);
const observable = subject.asObservable();
subject.next([{color: 'blue'}])
observable.pipe(first()).subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```

According to the docs:

> If called with no arguments, first emits the first value of the **source Observable, then completes**....

Does this mean that the source observable(the BehaviorSubject in this case) completes and you can no longer use it? As in you can no longer call `.next([...])` on it.

I'm trying to understand how can an observable complete if it doesnt have the `.complete()` method on it?

I was trying to look at the source code of `first()` which under the covers uses `take()` and in turn `take()` uses `lift()` so I was curious if somehow first operator returns a copy of the source observable(the subject) and completes that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source observable is not completing, what it completes is the subscription. You could have multiple subscriptions on your Observable source, in your case one BehaviorSubject.

```
subject.next([{color: 'blue'}])
subject.next([{color: 'red'}])
const subs1 = observable.pipe(first()).subscribe(v => console.log(v))
const subs2 = observable.subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```

In the example above you clearly see that the source is not completing, just the subscription.

I have created a Stackblitz if you want to try it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uv6h6i

Hope I got your point!

Cheers :)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. It `unsubscribes()` thus completing given observable, but the source can still be used! Awesome, thanks!